# MySQL query behaves differently when used as a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database, recursion, subquery

I have a query that we use to assess how many transactions we have in an area. Our areas are nested child/parent records (each area has a parent_id. One area can have multiple children).

One transaction has a widget, and a widget has an area.

To get a list of all children ids of an area (here area 2), I've used the following query:

```
SELECT id
FROM (
    SELECT id, parent_id FROM areas
    ORDER by parent_id, id
) areas_sorted,
(SELECT @pv := 2) initialisation
WHERE find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) > 0
AND @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)
```

This works well when run on its own, and it lists all areas including the children two levels deep.

However, when used as a subquery like this:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(transactions.id) as transaction_count,
SUM(transactions.widget_price * transactions.widget_quantity) as 'Sum'
FROM transactions
LEFT JOIN widgets ON widgets.id = transactions.widget_id
WHERE widgets.area_id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM (
        SELECT id, parent_id FROM areas
        ORDER by parent_id, id) areas_sorted,
        (SELECT @pv := 2
    ) initialisation
    WHERE find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) > 0
    AND @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)
) 
AND transactions.status = 'confirmed';
```

We only get the transactions for the widgets from the first level below area 2, not the ones the next child level.

Comment: These would help get you an answer: `1. Sample data` and `2. Expected result`